# only one input is required in them two by JQuery Plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, required

I have two inputs (text fields) required by JQuery Plug-in :

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="valid" />
&nbsp;<label class="error checked" generated="true" for="first_name">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="second_name" id="second_name" class="valid" />
&nbsp;<label class="error checked" generated="true" for="second_name">&nbsp;</label>
```

Those two are required by [JQuery Plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
var validator = jQuery("#FormCmj").validate({
    rules: 
    {
        first_name: "required",
        second_name: "required",

    },
    messages: 
    {
        first_name: "Écrivez votre adresse postale s'il vous plait!",
        second_name: "Écrivez le nom de votre ville s'il vous plait!",          
    },      
                                        });
                        }
            );
```

How can I make : **only one input is required in them two** : If user write first name, second name is not required or if user write his second  name, first name is not required.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add this to add a custom validation method:

   ```
   jQuery.validator.addMethod("eitherOne", function (value, element, param) {
       if (value !== "" || $(param.other).val() !== "") return true;
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. And use this to validate:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {

       var validator = jQuery("#FormCmj").validate({
           rules: {
               first_name: {
                   eitherOne: {
                       other: "#second_name"
                   }
               },
               second_name: {
                   eitherOne: {
                       other: "#first_name"
                   }
               }
           },
           messages: {
               first_name: {
                   eitherOne: "Écrivez votre adresse postale s'il vous plait!"
               },
               second_name: {
                   eitherOne: "Écrivez votre adresse postale s'il vous plait!"
               }
           },
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.addMethod("eitherOne", function (value, element, param)
 {
    if (value !== "" || jQuery(param.other).val() !== "") return true;
    return false;
 }
      )
</script>`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 
 var validator = jQuery("#FormJcm").validate({
  rules: 
  {
     first_name: {
                eitherOne:  {
                    other: "#second_name"
       }
         },
            second_name: {
                eitherOne: {
                    other: "#first_name"
       }
        },
  },
  messages: 
  {
   first_name: {
      eitherOne: "Votre first_name"
      },
   second_name: {
     eitherOne: "votre second_name"
        },   
  },
           });
       }
    );
</script>`